Having a problem with calling the class twice
import tkinter as tk
import math,time,random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image,ImageEnhance

start_time = time.time()

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=300, height=300,bg="black")
canvas.pack()

class Button():

    def While_drag(self,event):
        if self.drag:
            self.canv.coords(self.button,event.x,event.y)

    def start_drag(self,event):
        self.drag = True
        self.changeScl(30,True)

    def stop_drag(self,event):
        self.changeScl(5,False)
        self.drag = False
        if event.x >= self.SpotX and event.y >= self.SpotY and event.x <= self.SpotX+100 and event.y <= self.SpotY+100:
            window.after(1,lambda:self.canv.coords(self.button,self.SpotX+50,self.SpotY+50))
            window.after(1000,lambda:self.__init__(random.randint(30,200),random.randint(30,200),self.canv,self.image,100))

    def changeScl(self,x,enter):
        if x > 0:
            if enter:
                self.inc = 1
            else:
                self.inc = -1
            self.scale += self.inc
            window.after(10, lambda :self.changeScl(x-1,enter))
            self.Used_Img = self.set_brightness(1)
            self.canv.itemconfig(self.button,image=self.Used_Img)
        else:
            self.scale = self.TempScale

    def changeClr(self,x,enter):
        if x > 0:
            if enter:
                self.inc = 0.03
            else:
                self.inc = -0.03
            self.b += self.inc
            window.after(50 , lambda :self.changeClr(x-1,enter))
            self.Used_Img = self.set_brightness(self.b*self.b*self.b)
            print(self.b*self.b*self.b)
            self.canv.itemconfig(self.button,image=self.Used_Img)

    def Change_Frame(self,nextFrame):
        self.image = nextFrame
        #self.Used_Img = self.set_brightness(1)
        self.canv.itemconfig(self.button,image=self.Used_Img) 

    def set_brightness(self,brightness):
        self.img = Image.open(self.image).convert("RGBA")
        if self.scale:
            self.img = self.img.resize((self.scale,self.scale))

        self.enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(self.img)
        self.img = self.enhancer.enhance(brightness)
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)

    def __init__(self, x, y, canv,image,scale):
        self.drag = False
        self.image = image
        self.scale = scale
        self.TempScale = scale
        self.canv = canv
        self.canv.delete("all")
        self.Used_Img = self.set_brightness(1)
        self.b,self.inc = 1,0.01
        self.SpotX, self.SpotY = random.randint(0,200),random.randint(0,200)
        self.rect = canv.create_rectangle(self.SpotX,self.SpotY
                            ,self.SpotX+100,self.SpotY+100,fill="red")
        self.button = canv.create_image(x, y, image=self.Used_Img)
        canv.tag_bind(self.button, "<Enter>",lambda event: self.changeScl(5,True))
        canv.tag_bind(self.button, "<Leave>",lambda event: self.changeScl(5,False))
        canv.tag_bind(self.button, "<ButtonPress>",lambda event: self.start_drag(event))
        canv.tag_bind(self.button, "<ButtonRelease>",lambda event: self.stop_drag(event))
        self.canv.tag_bind(self.button,"<Motion>",lambda event: self.While_drag(event))

btn2 = Button(random.randint(30,200),random.randint(30,200),canvas,"Peter_Griffin.png",100)
btn1 = Button(random.randint(30,200),random.randint(30,200),canvas,"Hover.png",100)


window.mainloop()

I wrote a class that controls in a button and applies some hover and dragging effects to it. Then I tried to call it twice for two different images (btn1, btn2) but it ignores
the first call and just executes the second one. Why is that happening?

Why do you call self.canv.delete("all") inside Button.__init__()? It will delete all items created in the first instance when creating the second instance.

oh thats right, thanks for your hint.

there is good rule to use lower_case_names for variables - like self.temp_scale - and functions - like def while_drag(), def change_scl() , def change_frame(..., next_frame). See more: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code
